# COUNTA with FILTER using multiple conditions

Tags: google-sheets

I want to count the number of companies (Col B) that have a status of 'Our System' in Col A, grouped by their postcode area (e.g., SW10, SW11 etc)
As an example, the figures in the 'On System' column reflect what the formula should result in.

```
    A     |    B    |     C    | D | E |     F    |     G     |
----------|---------|----------|---|---|----------|-----------|
Status    | Name    | Postcode |   |   |   Area   | On System |
----------|---------|----------|---|---|----------|-----------|
On System | ABC Ltd | SW10 4ED |   |   |   SW10   |     1     |
----------|---------|----------|---|---|----------|-----------|
On System | XYZ Ltd | SW11 5RF |   |   |   SW11   |     2     |
----------|---------|----------|---|---|----------|-----------|
On System | GBH Ltd | SW11 5GR |   |   |   SW12   |     0     |
----------|---------|----------|---|---|----------|-----------|
Fresh     | DEF Ltd | SW11 7GG |   |   |   SW13   |     0     |
----------|---------|----------|---|---|----------|-----------|
Fresh     | GHI Ltd | SW12 5F5 |   |   |   SW14   |     0     |
----------|---------|----------|---|---|----------|-----------|
```

I've used the following formula (the below example counts companies in SW10 that are 'On System'), but with no success.

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(C:C, C:C=F3&" *", A:A="On System" )))
```

I'm under the impression that IFERROR removes empty results or something similar. Without it, I just get a value of 1, even if there are no SW10 rows with an On System status.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count the 'on system' with postal code SW10 try:

```
=sumproduct(A:A="On System", regexmatch(C:C, "SW10"))
```

Of course you can replace the strings with cell references.

Or -shorter- use COUNTIFS() with a wildcard (*)

```
=countifs(A:A, "On System", C:C, "SW10*")
```

Comment: Perfect, that solved the problem, thank you. I ended up using the shorter COUNTIFS function, FYI